# Let be $c>0$ and $M>0$ such that $|a_nc^n|\leq M$. Prove that $(-c,c)$ is in the interval of convergence of the power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

**The question:**

Given a power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, let be $c>0$ and $M>0$ such that $|a_nc^n|\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $(-c,c)$ is in the interval of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$.

**My work:**

First, I tried to do the calculus of interval of convergence using the formula

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}\right|=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$

but I don't know how to continue it.

Second, I suppose that the interval of convergence is known. Let be $|x|<R$ and let's suppose $|c|<|x|$, then

$$|a_nc^n|\leq M\Rightarrow|a_nx^n|\left|\dfrac{c}{x}\right|^n\leq M$$

on the other hand,

$$|a_nx^n|\left|\dfrac{c}{x}\right|^n\leq R\left|\dfrac{c}{x}\right|^n$$

and... that's it, I got stuck. I don't know how to continue too... but my ideia was to reach something like this:

$$|a_nc^n|\leq M\leq |a_nx^n|\leq R\quad\mbox{ or }\quad|a_nc^n|<|a_nx^n|\leq M\leq R$$

then I think I could say $(-c,c)$ is in the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $x\in (-c,c)$, note that $|a_nx^n|=|a_nc^n||\frac xc|^n\leq M|\frac xc|^n$

Note that since $|x/c|\lt 1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M|x/c|^n$ converges and hence the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_nx^n|$ follows by comparison test.